# D3.js Trying to use histogram layout to draw rectangles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I'm sort of new to Javascript and I am trying to create a histogram using d3.js. I've been following tutorials and examples of previously created histograms in d3 but cannot figure out how to make my rectangles appear.

My histogram currently contains 4 bins with the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4 in each bin symbolizing a color attribute of each data point in my dataset. When I do console.log(d) in the .attr "x" function it will appear as an a kind of array with 4 different indices, each with the total number of data points in my dataset with that specific color. Now I'm trying to make that "array" into rectangles but my width and height functions aren't correct. If someone could explain what d.dx and d.y do any why they're wrong that would be helpful. I'm using d3.v3.min.js as my script src value

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {

    var map = data.map(function (i) { return parseInt(i.color); })
    var histogram = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(4)(map)
    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);

    var bars = canvas.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(histogram)
    .enter()
    .append("g")

    bars.append("rect")

        .attr("x", function (d) 
        { 
            //console.log(d)
            return d.x * 5; })
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width",function(d) { return d.dx; })
        .attr("height", function(d) { d.y; })
        .attr("fill", "steelblue");


});
```

Comment: Could you maybe set up your example with data in plnkr or something? It is kind of hard to understand the problem right now, as your code seems ok. You can find compelet doucmentation about histograms [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Histogram-Layout.md).

Comment: @HuguesStefanski I'm not sure exactly how to use plnkr but I've created this code and nothing seems to show up. Since plnkr doesn't have a console you wouldn't be able to see what console.log(d) is outputting to the console. Using chrome's console, this is what outputs for console.log(d) https://i.gyazo.com/2db48d1f119a11c3af35137f980a4f5e.png https://i.gyazo.com/730f922dcd5fe7871bb75d1b4a5d3e71.png  Each of these array-values has its own x, dx, length and y values and I'm trying to draw the rectangles based on those values

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/noI7d7iiWAVycAQsxddf?p=info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [updated your plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/QbrIwP7WC9n5Zra4ucvY?p=preview) as follows.

```
bars.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x*100; })        
        .attr("y", 50)
        .attr("height", function(d) { return d.y * 10;})
        .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx*50;})

        .attr("fill", "steelblue")

        .on("mouseout", function() 
            {

                d3.select(this)
                .attr("fill", "steelblue");
        })
        .on("mouseover", function() 
            {

                d3.select(this)
                .attr("fill", "orange");
        });
```

Your code seems to work fine, only your elements are overlapping (also, d3 v4 was referenced instead of v3). What I did is:

- multiply `d.x` by 50 to space the elements
- multiplied `d.dx` by 50 to reduce the overlapping

As to your former questions:

- d.x corresponds to the extent of a bin, in your case 0.75 (4 ranges make between 1 and 4 make 0.75: 1+(0.75*4)=4)
  *d.y corresponds to the 'height' of a bin, i.e. the number of elements.